# How to access the passed-in parameters hash in FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

I am working on a web backend in Rails. My `Article` model is largely a wrapper that delegates most methods to the most recent `ArticleVersion`. When writing FactoryGirl factories, though, I was trying to create an :article_with_version factory that generates an `Article` and gives it a version, but I'm not sure how to forward parameters from the `Article` factory on to the `ArticleVersion`.

Here is the relevant code:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :versions, :class_name => "ArticleVersion"

  def title
    self.versions.last.title
  end # method title

  def contents
    self.versions.last.contents
  end # method contents
end # model Article

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :article_version do; end

  factory :article do; end

  factory :article_with_version, :parent => :article do
    after_create do |article|
      article.versions << Factory(:article_version, :article_id => article.id)
    end # after_create
  end # factory :article_with_version
end # FactoryGirl.define
```

What I would like to be able to do is call `Factory(:article_with_version, :title => "The Grid", :contents => "<h1>Greetings, programs!</h1>")` and have FactoryGirl pass those :title and :contents parameters on to the new `ArticleVersion` (or nil if those are omitted). Is there a way to access that hash of dynamic parameters that are passed on during Factory.create()?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using transient attributes like this:

```
factory :article_with_version, :parent => :article do
  ignore do
    title nil
    contents nil
  end

  after_create do |article, evaluator|
    article.versions = [FactoryGirl.create(:article_version, title: evaluator.title, contents: evaluator.contents)]
    article.save! 
  end
end
```

Just note that the attributes being ignored will not be set on the Article itself, although it looks like that is the behaviour you want in this case.